# Fitting images to document's margins in a docx file

Tags: microsoft-word, images, vba, docx

I've got a docx file with many figures, all do not fit the margins of the document.  I can manually adjust the sizes of the figures in the file, but would love to have some way to automate this (either from Word, from a command line tool, or any other means).

(PS: this is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829791/figure-sizes-with-pandoc-conversion-from-markodown-to-docx))

Comment: I'm sure this is possible with VBA, i.e. iterate through all embedded images in the doc and resize them to fit within the current page margins.

Comment: Thanks Karan, should I ask this in SO than?

Comment: Macros are on-topic here too, so I'd recommend waiting for answers here for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [Visual Basic Macro in Word to Resize/Center/Delete All Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955886/visual-basic-macro-in-word-to-resize-center-delete-all-images?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [How to resize all images in Word document](http://yuriy-okhmat.blogspot.ru/2011/07/how-to-resize-all-images-in-word.html) and [How can I resize a table to fit the page's width](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/FitTableToPage.htm) fixed the Kelly Tessena Keck solution a bit.

Now it's working with any available page width (don't forget to fix height, if needed, too) :

```
Sub PicturesFitPageWidth()
' ResizePic Macro
' Resizes an image

Shapes = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
InLines = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
'Sets the variables to loop through all shapes in the document, one for shapes and one for inline shapes.


'Calculate usable width of page

With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    WidthAvail = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin
End With

For ShapeLoop = 1 To Shapes
    MsgBox Prompt:="Shape " & ShapeLoop & " width: " & ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width
    If ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width > WidthAvail Then
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width = WidthAvail
    End If
Next ShapeLoop
'Loops through all shapes in the document.  Checks to see if they're too wide, and if they are, resizes them.

For InLineLoop = 1 To InLines
    MsgBox Prompt:="Inline " & InLineLoop & " width: " & ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width
    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width > WidthAvail Then
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width = WidthAvail
    End If
Next InLineLoop
'Loops through all shapes in the document.  Checks to see if they're too wide, and if they are, resizes them.

End Sub
```

Comment: Complains with "Shapes - Arguments not optional"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following VBA code. It counts the shapes in the document, checks their width against the available space on the page, and resizes if necessary.

Note that Word has two different collections for `Shapes` and `InlineShapes`, hence the two different `For` loops. Also, it uses a series of `If/ElseIf` statements to identify the page width based on standard paper sizes. Currently, the only options are letter size in either portrait or landscape, but you can add more `ElseIfs` for any paper sizes you need.

```
Sub ResizePic()
' ResizePic Macro
' Resizes an image

Shapes = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
InLines = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
'Sets the variables to loop through all shapes in the document, one for shapes and one for inline shapes.


RightMar = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin
LeftMar = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin
PaperType = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize
PageLayout = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation
'Sets up variables for margin sizes, paper type, and page layout.
' This is used to find the usable width of the document, which is the max width for the picture.

If PaperType = wdPaperLetter And PageLayout = wdPortrait Then
    WidthAvail = InchesToPoints(8.5) - (LeftMar + RightMar)
ElseIf PaperType = wdPaperLetter And PageLayout = wdLandscape Then
    WidthAvail = InchesToPoints(11) - (LeftMar + RightMar)
End If
'Identifies the usable width of the document, based on margins and paper size.

For ShapeLoop = 1 To Shapes
    MsgBox Prompt:="Shape " & ShapeLoop & " width: " & ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width
    If ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width > WidthAvail Then
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(ShapeLoop).Width = WidthAvail
    End If
Next ShapeLoop
'Loops through all shapes in the document.  Checks to see if they're too wide, and if they are, resizes them.

For InLineLoop = 1 To InLines
    MsgBox Prompt:="Inline " & InLineLoop & " width: " & ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width
    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width > WidthAvail Then
        ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(InLineLoop).Width = WidthAvail
    End If
Next InLineLoop
'Loops through all shapes in the document.  Checks to see if they're too wide, and if they are, resizes them.

End Sub
```

Comment: For me it just looped through the pictures in document and they are gone from my view(. It's a pity as the script looks like a kind of working one.

Comment: I think the script should check if the shape is a pic, as for a document with just two pics it did find 5 shapes and set their width to zero, so they did gone from the view.

Comment: Pics disappeared. Useless

Answer (score 0):

Found one that works on msdn forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6bb7f6a1-5031-4404-820a-dc9adafd36f9/auto-size-inline-shapes-to-fit-margins-macro?forum=worddev